# Unique authentication for various apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have three rails apps (two with rails 3.0.3 and the other one with rails 2.3.8), in all of them I'm using devise for authentication, so every user needs a username and password for each app. So I need have an unique database of users for all the apps. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the question right, is let all of them share a database, or at the least a table. This way devise will not create a user that already exists and you can access your user for authentication in each of the apps. You just have to keep the user models for each app working the same way.